# Change favicon pdf files

Tags: php, apache, drupal

I was wondering if it's possible to change a favicon for a pdf file that is being opened in firefox using the adobe reader plugin? When I checked the source code it's using `embed`. Any info on how to change this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's using `embed`, then you just need to specify `<link rel="shortcut icon" href"somepath/somefavicon.ico">` in the HTML head.

Edit: Browser support for this is sketchy. Latest releases of Firefox, Opera and Safari will successfully display the favicon in this case, but Chrome and IE8 won't.

Answer (score 0):

you can also change your apache settings to define the favicon depending on your setup

this is from my httpd.conf that came with MAMP

```
#
# AddIcon* directives tell the server which icon to show for different
# files or filename extensions.  These are only displayed for
# FancyIndexed directories.
#
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core

AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a favicon.ico to the root of your site, then your pdf-s opened on that site will actually have that favicon. You can generate transparent ico-s from png-s with online favicon genereators.

Example:
Your favicon is reachable in:
www.yourdomain.com/favicon.ico
Then your pdf will show this favicon in the Acrobat plugin tab:
www.yourdomain.com/something/something.pdf